# Hiding the system navbar

Tags: android

I have a video player application and I am struggling to hide the navbar 100% of the time. My issue arises when I quickly tap the screen twice. I would assume the navbar would hide along with the remaining system UI on the second touch, but it stays on screen. This does not occur if I wait a half second or more between taps.

Debugging the application shows that the `hideSystemUI()` method is being called at the appropriate time, it just isn't performing as expected.

Any idea on what might be wrong? Tested on 5.1.1.

Relevant code:

MediaPlayerWrapper

```
public void hideSystemUI()
{
    setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN ); // hide status bar*/

}
```

CustomMediaController extends MediaController

```
public void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility)
{
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    if (!isShowing())
    {
        _mediaPlayerWrapper.hideSystemUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try setting window flag activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: Try reading up on Android's documentation. It is handled differently based on version of Android. https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: @RamIndani, it looks like that didn't work. The system UI seems to be always visible now. I edited my original post to include the version of Android I'm currently testing on, which could be why the suggestion didn't work.